# ASP .net core HttpGet with parameter resulting Bad Request

Tags: typescript, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

So I have a service using Axios to call my C# API. Since I want to select specific data, I use a get method with a parameter.

Here's my service:

```
let response = await Axios.get('/api/get-report', {
   params: filter
});
```

Here's my filter object in typescript:

```
export interface FilterModel {
  employeeId?: string;
  Month?: Date;
  from?: Date;
  to?: Date;
}
```

Here's the model on the server:

```cs
public class AttendanceReportFilterModel
{
    public string EmployeeId { set; get; }
    public DateTime? Month { set; get; }
    public DateTime? From { set; get; }
    public DateTime? To { set; get; }
}
```

And here's my C# API:

```cs
[HttpGet("get-report")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(FilterModel filter)
{
    var Detail = await Service.GetReport(filter);
    if (Detail == null)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Not Found");
    }

    return Ok(Detail);
}
```

Whenever I call my service, it always returns `Bad Request`.

Does anybody know why and how to fix this?

Comment: When you are making request you are adding some parameters. Can you please provide URL from network? It seems that you are sending invalid date.

Comment: Show `FilterModel` as defined on server side. Also show the `filter` params sent from client. You most likely have the `[ApiController]` and the filter is defaulting to bad request because of a missing or malformed parameter value.

Comment: Does it get hit while you debug or it doesn't even find the Url ? Whereas am not sure how you pass a body for get ?

Comment: @Nkosi you can see my model in my post aboce, i aleady updated it. also i already use [ApiController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

> [FromQuery]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport([FromQuery] FilterModel filter)
```

So since you are doing binding to object you need to say where to take them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes.

Or you can do it just with parameters

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReport(string EmployeeId, DateTime? Month = null, DateTime? FromMonth = null, DateTime? ToMonth = null)
```

Comment: there is no FromUri
only FromBody, Form, Header, Query, Route, Services

which one i have to use?

Comment: @hphp updated my answer. I did posted for old aspnet. In core there is fromQuery

Comment: @hphp well at least its not bad request :) Seems to be that endpoint is hit but error in your code

Comment: ah yeah.. it's hit.. thanks... now i just have to debug my code logic
thanks